# Ordering field in sql table - updating from jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql, sorting

I have some records in a MYSQL table that can be ordered and reordered by the user using jquery.

My question is what is the most efficient way of updating the sort order of a table.  The most obvious method is to have a integer field called order where the first record is 1, the second is 2 etc.

Say a record is inserted in the middle of the list, then all the records after it are updated by one to make room for the new record.  Alternatively I could order them in gaps of 10 or 100, so the first record is 100, the second is 200 and so on, then there is room to add a new record without scuffling, but there would need to be a whole table reordering now and again to avoid running out of room.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Maybe you should consider using datatables like this one: http://www.datatables.net/[link text](http://www.datatables.net/) or this one: [http://www.trirand.com/blog/](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)

Comment: I really like the datatables option but I need the ability for the user to reorder the rows manually, then I hit this problem with updating the database.

Comment: If you need sorting rows check jquery ui sortable plugin here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/. You can after sort make an ajax call and update the order in db table ordering column

Comment: I'm ok with the jquery aspect, my question is about how best to update the database without having to update every row following the newly inserted row.  Have updated my question to make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column called 'order', or something, to hold the location of the item.
on an insert incriment the order column for items with an order >= the location to be inserted. a delete wouold be the opposite. reordering could use the same increase/decrease order column, it just needs additional functionality to reassign the moved items order value.

Comment: I was trying to find a way that did not need potentially a lot of records to be updated on the fly.  If a record is inserted near the beginning there could be up to a 1000 records updated in this application.